# How to aggregate using water years (oct 1 2008- sept 31 2009)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data measuring precipitation daily using R. My dates are in format 2008-01-01 and range for 10 years. I am trying to aggregate from 2008-10-01 to 2009-09-31 but I am not sure how. Is there a way in aggregate to set a start date of aggregation and group.

My current code is

```
data<- aggregate(data$total_snow_cm, by=list(data$year), FUN = 'sum')
```

but this output gives me a sum total of the snowfall for each year from jan - dec but I want it to include oct / 08 to sept / 09.

Comment: You need to share a small sample of your data and it's expected output before anyone can provide any useful help. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data are in long format, I'd do something like this:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 #make sure R knows your dates are dates - you mention they're 'yyyy-mm-dd', so
 yourdataframe <- yourdataframe %>% 
                  mutate(yourcolumnforprecipdate = ymd(yourcolumnforprecipdate) 


 #in this script or another, define a water year function
 water_year <- function(date) {
               ifelse(month(date) < 10, year(date), year(date)+1)}

 #new wateryear column for your data, using your new function
 yourdataframe <- yourdataframe %>% 
                  mutate(wateryear = water_year(yourcolumnforprecipdate)

 #now group by water year (and location if there's more than one) 
 #and sum and create new data.frame

 wy_sums <- yourdataframe %>% group_by(locationcolumn, wateryear) %>% 
            summarize(wy_totalprecip = sum(dailyprecip))
```

For more info, read up on the `tidyverse` 's great sublibrary called `lubridate` -
where the `ymd()` function is from. There are others like `ymd_hms()`. `mutate()` is from the tidyverse's `dplyr` libary. Both libraries are extremely useful!

Comment: Great! Welcome to SO! Just FYI, as @Shree mentioned, you'll by far get the best answers if you include some sample data (like a small piece of your timeseries) with your question. Say for this one, including ten or so days with precip from say `2008-09-25` to `2008-10-05`, would be enough for others to quickly cut and paste your data and come up with solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give the actual answer to the question, where the `aggregate()` way was asked.

You may use `with()` to wrap the data specification around `aggregate()`. In the `with()` you can define date intervals as you can with numbers.

```
df1.agg <- with(df1[as.Date("2008-10-01") <= df1$year & df1$year <= as.Date("2009-09-30"), ], 
                aggregate(total_snow_cm, by=list(year), FUN=sum))
```

Another way is to use `aggregate()`'s formula interface, where `data` and, hence, also the interval can be specified inside the `aggregate()` call.

```
df1.agg <- aggregate(total_snow_cm ~ year, 
                     data=df1[as.Date("2008-10-01") <= df1$year & 
                                df1$year <= as.Date("2009-09-30"), ], FUN=sum)
```

#### Result

```
head(df1.agg)
#         year total_snow_cm
# 1 2008-10-01           171
# 2 2008-10-02           226
# 3 2008-10-03           182
# 4 2008-10-04           129
# 5 2008-10-05           135
# 6 2008-10-06           222
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(total_snow_cm=sample(120:240, 4018, replace=TRUE),
                  year=seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2010-12-31"), by="day"))
```